# navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition slow on Android stock browser

Tags: android, mobile, browser, geolocation

I'm calling

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition
```

on a stock (i.e. 'default') Android browser, on an Android tablet, to get the user's current position. The 1st time it's really quick, then it becomes really slow (5-10 secs) for subsequent calls. When I *debug* the stock Android browser using the Chrome developer tools, then it's always quick. I'm using https, and it makes no difference if I set:

```
enableHighAccuracy: false
```

And if I use navigator.geolocation.watchPosition for the 2nd call and above, it doesn't help (so it's not like the IE issue where navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition can only be successfully called once).

What is going on and what could be causing this? There's no indication of anything in the console. I can't see any timeouts on other functions that could be interfering with this. It also always works quickly using the stock Android browser on an Android phone. I've tried opening maps on the tablet device I'm using, and restarting the device, but I still get the behaviour. If I disable 'settings > connections > Location (High accuracy) on the device, then detecting the current location doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 0):

It's a Samsung Galaxy Tab 2. I did a soft-reset (hold down power and volume down key for 10s). Now it works. This is a known fix that can help reset GPS, however I'm not using a mobile network, I'm using wi-fi so I don't understand why this would make a difference. Any answers that could help explain this are appreciated!